# Does PHP or cURL cache their web responses somehow?

Tags: php, curl, get

I have a php script making requests to some web site. I run this script from command line so no web server on my side is involved. Just pure PHP and a shell.

The response is split into pages so I need to make multiple requests to gain all the data with one script run. Obviously, the request's URL is identical except one parameter. Nothing complicated:

```php
$base_url = '...';
$pages = ...; // a number I receive elsewhere
$delay = ...; // a delay to avoid too many requests 
$p = 0;
while ($p < $pages) {
   $url = $base_url . "&some_param=$p";
   ... // Here cURL takes it's turn because of cookies
   sleep($delay);
}
```

The pages I get this way look all the same - like the first one that was requested. (So I get just a repetitive list multiplied by the number of pages.)

I decided that it happens because of some caching on the web server's end which persists despite of an additional random parameter I pass. Closing and reinitializing cURL session doesn't help as well.

I also noticed that if I quickly fix the initial `$p` value manually (so requests start from different page) and then launch the script again, the result changes. I do it quicker than `$delay` value.
It means that two different requests made from the *same script run* give *same result*, while two different requests made from two *different script runs* give *different results*, regardless of delay between the requests. So it can't be just caching on the responded side.

I tried to work that around and wrapped the actual request in a separate script which I run using `exec()` from the main script. So there is (should be, I consider) a separate shell instance for any single page request, and those requests should not share any kind of cache between them.
Despite of that, I keep getting the same page again. The code looks something like that:

```php
$pages = ...; 
$delay = ...; 
$p = 0;
$command_stub = 'php get_single_page.php';
while ($p < $pages) {
   $command = $command_stub . " $p";
   exec($command, $response);
   // $response is the same again for different $p's
   sleep($delay);
}
```

If I again change the starting page manually in the script, I get a result for that page all over again. Until I change it once more. And so on. Several minutes may pass between two runs of the main script, and it still yields identical result until I switch the number by hand.

I can't comprehend why this is happening. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: The query parameters passed, how you expect them to interact with the page, and the actual cURL requests would go a long way in helping solve your problem. If you just want a simple answer to the title, I believe Richard has it covered below (and a suggested new troubleshooting point)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Curl certainly doesn't retain anything between executions unless configured to do so (e.g.: setting a cookie file).

I suspect the server is expecting a session token of some sort (cookie or other HTTP header are my guess). Without the session token it will just ignore the request for subsequent pages.

Comment: I duplicated every HTTP header of the successful request using the browser (if I log in and just open the page it loads correctly) and the cookie. And it still keeps passing me the same page all over again. Actually it is even more confusing than if it would not give any content at all. I would understand that. But the behaviour I observe is completely unexplainable to me. Well, probably I'm missing something. I'll go on researching...